# EF - Adding object to collection

Tags: entity-framework

I have a Parent table, which has a 1-many relationship with a Child table. When I create a new child, do how do I associate it properly with the parent? Do I have to add the child to the database first with something like context.Children.add(child)? Or can I just say context.Parent.Children.add(child)? I am just confused on the best way to add a child to a parent's collection and set their relationship to eachother.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a child to a child collection of an existing parent, EF will insert the child, with its proper foreign key to parent.

```
using(var context = new Entities())
{
    context.Parent.Children.Add(child);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: This wasn't working for me because of how I was getting my context I think.I will try to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Do not persist the context across calls, in nearly every scenario a context should be short lived. (ie, created and then immediately disposed after the unit or work is complete)

Comment: That is good advice, thanks. Tracking was off for the set, so it wasn't updating when I would save the changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need.  You do not need a separate call to Context.ChildCollection.AddObject(Child).

`Parent.ChildCollection.Add(Child);`

Comment: I see. That is what I was doing and it was not working. I think it is because of how I am getting my context. I was using a set and navigation properties.